# Not able to send the desired key to dropdown list using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape a website where I need to select the distance given by a dropdown but while sending the keys, it is not taking the value which is send by program but it is taking some random value within the drop down. Please help on this

I tried to use XPath and send the value using send_keys but all in vain. Nothing has helped me.

```
url = 'https://www.solargard.com/find-a-dealer/'
x = '98357'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
loc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="zip"]')
loc.send_keys(x)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-id = 
'distance_metric']").send_keys('150 mi')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for = 'select_all']").click()
time.sleep(5)
sub = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type = 'submit' and @class 
= 'btn btn-primary upper']")
sub.click()
```

I want to select the max value available in distance which is 150 mi. It would be great if someone can help me as I am quite new in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
(//li[@class='divider']/preceding-sibling::li)[last()]
```

Below is the code that you can use.

```
url = 'https://www.solargard.com/find-a-dealer/'
driver.get(url)

loc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="zip"]')
loc.send_keys('98357')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[data-id='distance_metric']").click()
maxMilesEle = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"(//li[@class='divider']/preceding-sibling::li)[last()]")))
maxMilesEle.location_once_scrolled_into_view
maxMilesEle.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for = 'select_all']").click()
# time.sleep(5)
sub = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type = 'submit' and @class= 'btn btn-primary upper']")
sub.click()
```

Make sure to import the below.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but I am getting "ElementClickInterceptedException" excepetion while running the code. Any idea why am I getting this exception

Comment: It is not able to perform the action at this line: maxMilesEle.click()

Comment: `maxMilesEle.location_once_scrolled_into_view` this line should scroll to that element before click. I am able to run script successfully. Can you try running with `driver.maximize_window()`

Comment: Actually I had already done the maximizing the window. You are right that it is scrolling to the correct element but somehow it is not able to click that.

Comment: hmm. Then replace that click line with this `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",maxMilesEle)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196021/discussion-between-supputuri-and-abhishek-yadav).